# How to Create NuGet Packages From .Net Core RC2 Class Libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, .net-core-rc2

I have a solution in Visual Studio with 12 projects. I would like to create a nuget package from Visual Studio, but it appears the "Produce outputs on build" that was there from RC1 is missing.

I can go ahead and create a script that goes to each folder and call "dotnet pack", but is there an option in Visual Studio that I am missing to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add this to your `project.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "postcompile": [
    "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%"
  ]
}
```

This will run the `dotnet pack` command which will pack your build output produced after compilation into a NuGet package. For more info, see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3066).

I'm not sure how to only do this in release mode, so I've asked that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596115/how-to-run-scripts-based-on-solution-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2).

**UPDATE**

Updated the answer based on the other question.

Comment: I always get "Dependency Could not be resolved" error if I try to add a reference with this nuget package which created with postcompile? Have ever run into any problem like this? Thanks

Comment: If you want to build a NuGet package with release binaries, all you need to do is add the -c / --configuration switch and use release as the argument.
[quoted from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/creating-nuget-packages)

Comment: This only packages up the exe, not any of the numerous other dependencies in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I don't believe there is an option to do this automatically in VS. You can look into using [NuProj](http://nuproj.net/) to do this if you like.