# Publishing NuGet packages with custom metadata with .NET Core

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package

I read this beforehand (works a treat!)

[How to Create NuGet Packages From .Net Core RC2 Class Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464874/how-to-create-nuget-packages-from-net-core-rc2-class-libraries)

I'm not sure how to add metadata, though. My current process uses [Nuget Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer). I'm currently having to do this manually, and I really shouldn't have to!

Here is an example of what I would like to add to my project, without the UI

[image]

Is it possible to add this information anywhere inside my VS2015 solution, and have it added to my nuget package automatically?

*P.S. if the answer is "you need a .nuspec file..." can you document the process of how this works in VS2015, because I don't see how VS would respect the contents of the file.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `.nuspec` file, just a `project.json` file (which you should already have).

The equivalent properties to your screenshot would be:

```
{
  "name": "NewCo",
  "authors": [ "NewCo" ],
  "description": "Core",
  "packOptions": {
    "owners": [ "NewCo" ],
  },
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

And of course, all the other `project.json` stuff like dependencies (which I've left out of the above for brevity). The [project.json reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json) is helpful here.

When you use `dotnet pack`, the above properties are parsed and used for the package metadata.

Comment: How do I set the package ID?

Comment: @series0ne According to the reference, you should be able to use `name`. If you leave it out, the current folder name is used. I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: Is there an alternative for .Net4.x projects?
Because we are modifying nuspec files on the fly before packing.
Would be nice.