# Cannot add Nuget package to .NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I can add my Nuget package to a standard .NET Framework project but it does not work when I try to add it to a .NET Core project.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Meysam</authors>
    <owners>Meysam</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="ConsoleApp1\CustomClass\CustomClass.cs" target="content\CustomClass\CustomClass.cs" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: The `<files/>` tag in the nuspec file is where you tell it what to include in the built package.  You need to reference the project output, not the cs file.

Comment: See this for some info that *may* be relevant... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464874/how-to-create-nuget-packages-from-net-core-rc2-class-libraries

Comment: I found solution in.net core this blog:
https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, in .net core must be used contentFiles instead content in .net framework.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
 <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Meysam</authors>
    <owners>Meysam</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>

    <contentFiles>
      <files include="cs/*.*/**" buildAction="Compile" />
    </contentFiles>

  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="ConsoleApp1\CustomClass\CustomClass.cs" target="contentFiles\cs\any\CustomClass" />
  </files>

</package>
```